Uninstalling Commerce Authorize.net: How to Remove Content?
I'm trying to uninstall the Commerce Authorize.net module. I've deleted the payment gateways I was using. When I try to uninstall the module using the web interface I get this error:

The following reasons prevent Commerce Authorize.net from being
uninstalled:

There is data for the bundle eCheck on the entity type Payment method. Please remove all content before uninstalling the module.
There is data for the bundle Authorize.net (Accept.js) on the entity type Payment. Please remove all content before uninstalling the
module.


How can I remove this content? I hope it doesn't mean that I have to delete old orders that used those payment methods.

If you don't want to delete the orders, you can edit the orders and change the payment method to something else, such as a dummy payment method.

Thanks, that did the trick.

Without looking at your backend, it reads to me like you have payment method entities on your site that need to be deleted. These would be correlated to user accounts, though I don’t think we have a View for admins to see all payment methods on the site. You could always create on and delete the various entities from there.
